# Why does Rails fail to run a single rake test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem that I am having with my test database. I am currently following alongside Agile Web Development 4 and going through the chapters. Somewhere along 3/4ths of the way I discovered that my test database was persisting data and am currently trying to find out where exactly this is taking place. I have an orders_controller_test.rb file that I am trying to run.

When I execute

`rake test:controllers`

`rake test test/controllers/orders_controller_test.rb`

```
rake test
```

the tests execute and the data is persisted. I want to go test by test one at a time and am executing this command to do so:

```
rake test test/controllers/orders_controller_test.rb name_of_test
```

as shown in the Rails 4 guide. The execution of this command yields this:

[image]

As you can see it executes the tests but doesn't actually do so. No assertions are made and this is confusing/frustrating me. I've referred to this web article and have tried the methods in it. [Different ways to run rails tests](http://flavio.castelli.name/2010/05/28/rails_execute_single_test/)

Why is this not executing correctly. This is immensely frustrating and I suspect it is something simple. Can someone please help pinpoint what is possibly going on? Help would be greatly appreciated.

-----EDIT-----------

Controller tests

```
require 'test_helper'

class OrdersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup 
    @order = orders(:one)
  end

  def teardown
    @order = nil 
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:orders)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :redirect
  end

  test "should create order" do
    assert_difference('Order.count') do
      post :create, order: { address: @order.address, email: @order.email, name: @order.name, pay_type: @order.pay_type }
    end

    assert_redirected_to store_path
  end

  test "should show order" do
    get :show, id: @order
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @order
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update order" do
    patch :update, id: @order, order: { address: @order.address, email: @order.email, name: @order.name, pay_type: @order.pay_type }
    assert_redirected_to order_path(assigns(:order))
  end

  test "should destroy order" do
    assert_difference('Order.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @order
    end

    assert_redirected_to orders_path
  end

  test "requires item in cart" do
    get :new
    assert_redirected_to store_path
    assert_equal flash[:notice], 'Your cart is empty'
  end

  test "should get new order" do
    item = LineItem.new
    item.build_cart
    item.product = products(:ruby)
    item.save!
    binding.pry
    session[:cart_id] = item.cart.id
    get :new
    binding.pry
    assert_response :success
  end 

end
```

Comment: maybe show your test too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll copy and paste them up. They're taken straight from Agile Web 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your test method name is incorrect. I believe you have to prepend `test_` to the method name.

```
rake test test/controllers/orders_controller_test.rb -n test_should_get_new_order
# or 
rake test test/controllers/orders_controller_test.rb - test_should_get_new_order
```

Rails converts `test 'some name' do` to `test_some_name` to run the test(s).